# How to interpret operators “+” and “-” in DIRECTION and RDS_DIRECTION?

Tags: here-api

Under RDS-TMC, we have the values RDS_DIRECTION and DIRECTION that can either have the value '+' or '-'. What do these values represent?

I read the developer's guide and went through additional documentation, but did not find any explanation of these parameters. Could maybe someone clarify this for me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When traffic becomes congested, a queue of vehicles begins to build up in the opposite direction to the driving direction. The value can be "+" or "-".

> The value "-" indicates that the traffic is queued in the opposite
>   direction to the driving direction.

Comment: Thanks for the info!
I'm not sure whether I understand this correctly though.

An example scenario: We want to group all congestion items for a particular roadway based on the direction. Does this mean we have to filter out the "-" direction items, since they do not actually correspond to a congestion on the road direction we are talking about?